# Display Database Values on Different HTML Dropdown Selections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list that is imported with data from a table in a database. Depending on what is selected, I want to display a table that shows the necessary information that correlates to the number that was selected in the dropdown list. So, for example, if I select a MR_ID of 1 in the dropdown list, I want the Supp_ID values (can be more than 1 value) to be displayed in a table. How can I do this?

The table is only 2 columns, MR_ID (which is what is displayed in the dropdown list) and Supp_ID.

Here are my queries used for the foreach loops, my HTML/PHP that I have so far, also followed by the little bit of JavaScript

```
$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Table_Name";
$sql_one = "SELECT CAST(Supp_ID AS INT) AS Supp_ID FROM Table_Name";

$users = $dbh->query($sql);
$users_one = $dbh->query($sql_one);
```

HTML/PHP:

```
    <!-- Dropdown List -->
    <select name="master_dropdown" id="mr_id" onChange="updatetable(this.form);">
    <option selected value="select">Choose a MR_ID</option>
        <?php foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user) { ?>
            <option data-name="<?php echo $user['MR_ID'];?>">
                <?php echo $user['MR_ID'];?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>

<!-- Table -->
<p> 
    <div id="table_div">
        <table border="1" id="index_table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <td>MR ID</td>
                <td>Supplier ID</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($users_one->fetchAll() as $supp) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="mr_id"><div id="dropdown_selection"></div></td>
                <td class="supp_id"><?php echo $supp['Supp_ID']?></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This JavaScript code reads what was selected in the dropdown list but that is the extent of what it does.

```
function updatetable(myForm) {

    var selIndex = myForm.master_dropdown.selectedIndex;
    var selName = myForm.master_dropdown.options[selIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("dropdown_selection").innerHTML = String(selName);
}
```

Comment: what is the relation with MR_ID and SUPP_ID? there is no relation in the table for the selected MR_ID

Comment: The MR_ID field is related to a field in another table that is not being used here. There is no relation to the Supp_ID as far as I'm concerned though.

Comment: Are you looking to Ajax the data in, or are you simply going to store the data in a javascript variable that basically then fills the tables when you change the option?

Comment: Not exactly sure...what would be best? I would be open to either method in order to fix this problem

Comment: Typically, ajaxing is best, as you can call the data you only need.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I figured that might be the easier way.

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to do it then?

Comment: No, not exactly unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130223/discussion-between-a-lau-and-rataiczak24).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax should look something like this:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "table_drawing.php",
    method: "get", //can be post or get, up to you
    data: {
        mr_id : mr_id    
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        //Might want to delete table and put a loading screen, otherwise ignore this
        // $("#table_div").html(loading_screen);
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#table_div").html(data); // table_div is the div you're going to put the table into, and 'data' is the table itself.
    }
});
```

In table_drawing.php you will be drawing the table based off of mr_id's input.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but if you see this can you join in on our chat that is in the comments above? I have a question.